# Ubuntu + Strapi: nginx CORS on proxy pass: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: ubuntu, cors

I have set up nginx to redirect http request to https for my strapi server. However, I always got CORS issue when using https (when I use http, it is going through). Currently, this is my nginx default config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337; # Assuming Strapi runs on port 1337
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        }

   }


server {
root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name prj666.ddns.net; # managed by Certbot
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337; # Assuming Strapi runs on port 1337
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/prj666.ddns.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/prj666.ddns.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = prj666.ddns.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name prj666.ddns.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

 location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337; # Assuming Strapi runs on port 1337
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/prj666.ddns.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/prj666.ddns.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I have twisted it multiple ways (sorry for the format), I have tried add header and proxy_set_header inside the location / {}, but it does not working.

So I want to ask, is there any more solution to this ?

Also, here is my Strapi configuration:

```
    name: "strapi::cors",
    config: {
      enabled: true,
      headers: "*",
      origin: [
        "http://localhost:1337",
        "http://localhost:3000",
        "https://ood-system-frontend.vercel.app",
        "http://prj666.ddns.net:1337",
        "https://prj666.ddns.net:1337",
      ],
    },
  },
```

Comment: Also, when I tried to connect it via http, seems like the response does not get the cors header and it is the problem: 
``` ​
bodyUsed: true
​
headers: Headers { "content-length" → "41418", "content-type" → "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
​​
<entries>
​​​
"content-length": "41418"
​​​
"content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"